# How can I copy and paste using range variables from two sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, offset, worksheet

I am trying to copy data from one sheet in a workbook to another (names "Sheet1" and "Clean Data"). rRow is the source range in Sheet1, while rPaste is the location I want to copy to in "Clean Data". First, the new row should have the variables sSkillset and sDate, which is currently working fine, but then it should append the whole row of data from rRow. I can't find a way to do that without generating a mismatch or object error.

```
rPaste.Value = sSkillset
Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(0, 1)
rPaste.Value = sDate
Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(0, 1)
For Each rCell In rRow
'Copy rCell contents to rPaste
Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(0, 1)
Next rCell
Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(1, -14) 'I need a line so that next time rPaste is called, it is ready at column A of the next row
```

The output should be in one row:
[sSkillset][sDate][rRowCell1][rRowCell2].....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
rPaste.Value = sSkillset
rPaste.Offset(0, 1).Value = sDate

rPaste.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, rRow.Columns.Count).Value = rRow.Value

Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(1, 0)
```